# Enlarging concrete img in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, foreach

I have a website, where I display posts. The posts get data from a database, and are reached from a foreach loop in the DataTable where the data is located.
I want to go back and forth in making the pictures bigger and smaller. Classic function.

Here is the code:

```
var dataTablePrispevky = Model.PrecistProfilovePrispevky().ProfilePosts;

foreach (DataRow dr3 in dataTablePrispevky.Rows)
{
    <div class="OnePost">
        <div class="NickName">
            @Models.User.UserName
        </div>
        <div class="TimeAndDate">
            <text name="DateTimee">@dr3[3].ToString()</text>
        </div>
        <div class="TextPrispevkuProfil">
            @{
                string text2 = @dr3[1].ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />");
            }
            @Html.Raw(text2)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="profilepostIMG" id="obrazekcontainerProfil">
        <div>
            @{
                var dtIMG = Model.Obrazky(dr3[4].ToString()).Images;
                foreach (DataRow dr1 in dtIMG.Rows)
                {
                    if(dr1[1].ToString().Contains("NULL"))
                    {
                        <img class="obrprofil" src="~/NoProfilePicture.jpg" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <img class="obrprofil" onclick="ZvetsitObrazekProfil()" id="obrazekcontainer" src="@dr1[1]" />
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
}
```

Since I'm in the foreach loop, the concrete pictures aren't identifiable, I did some basic JavaScript to change the CSS of the container and picture. But when I click any image, it always enlarges the picture in the last post.

The basic javascript function:

```
function ZvetsitObrazekProfil() {
    const element2 = document.getElementById("obrazekcontainer")
    if (element2.style.transform === "scale(1.8)") {

        element2.style.transform = "scale(1)";
    }
    else {

        element2.style.transform = "scale(1.8)";
    }
}
```

Comment: To increase size of a HTML img element, use it's attributes width and height through JavaScript, HTML or CSS. It is nothing related to c# foreach loop. But MDN recommends not to alter the size of image here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML.

Comment: //it always enlarges the picture in the last post.// Do you mean another image in the same web page got enlarged ? If yes that particular image element might have same id "obrazekcontainer"

Comment: @SivaSankaran Yes thats exactly it, the foreach loop creates the html <img> element as many times as there is posts, the @dr[1] is a path to the image from database, so the img elements all have same id, and i dont know how to differ them to enlarge just the concrete one

Comment: But the value you are assigning to src attribute looks not correct so I believe all images would not be displayed. If you have any other image other than these profile images in the same page with same id, clicking one of the profile image will enlarge that other image

Comment: the value assigned to src attribute is absolutely right, all images are displayed perfectly, its about the fact that when the <img> is displayed multiple times just with different SRC but same class same id same everything, except the src, i dont really know how to differ which one was clicked :/

Comment: now I got it. Question is not conveying the actual requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since im in the foreach loop, the concrete pictures arent
> identifiable,

The actual problem which I understand is the image is not displayed in the web page. The reason is you are not assigning the path to image file in src attribute of img HTML element.

```
<img class="obrprofil" onclick="ZvetsitObrazekProfil()" id="obrazekcontainer" src="@dr1[1]" />
```

Here you assigned the entire data table to the src.

```
<img class="obrprofil" onclick="ZvetsitObrazekProfil()" id="obrazekcontainer" src="@dr1[1].ToString()" />
```

From your code I believe the file path is in second column of the Data table. So above change will work. It will display the image in web page

Comment: the images are displaying perfectly, its about the identification of the image, everything about the <img> element is the same for every image, and i dont really know how could i differ it. 
Also im pretty much a newbie in javascript, so any in depth explanation of changing CSS through JavaScript for the clicked image would be appreciated

Comment: @Drapys Assign a concatenated dynamic string as a value to id attribute.  simply you can have a counter variable initialized to 0 before starting foreach. Inside foreach increment the counter variable. So each iteration will have unique counter value.  id="obrazekcontainer"+"@counter". so, each img element will have unique value.

Comment: That solved it, didnt think of that for some reason, thank you